# Can the replicas be read directly for an Azure Storage Account with LRS (Locally Redundant Storage)?

Tags: azure, storage

An Azure Storage Account created with LRS has 3 replicas. Is there a way to read the copies of this data?

Comment: I know that @gaurav has answered this, but, I'm just curious: What's the use case?

Comment: Read through-put would be increased by reading across the drives. After the original write the drive is just read from and the file is large. Multiple drives can be written to but there is an added cost in time and money.

Comment: Ah. So... you're thinking about Azure Storage as a "disk to read/wrote from/to." That's not how it works. There is no single disk. You need to think of it as black-box behind the API, with a per-blob throughput and per-blob (and per-storage-account) transaction/sec limit.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is no. You can't specify from which replica copy of your data you want to read.

Answer (score 2):

We can't just tack -secondary on the account name in the connection string.  The AccountName={...} field in a standard connection string is used both to infer the resource URL and for signing.  When using RA-GRS, you must use the -secondary endpoint to route requests, but still sign the request with the account name (without the -secondary).  If  you try to do an RA-GRS read (either with the client library or storage explorer), you cannot simply add -secondary in the connection string: this will route requests to the right place, but authentication will fail since they are attempting to sign the request with a "account-secondary" which does not actually exist.

So, instead of

AccountName=account-secondary;AccountKey=XXX;**EndpointSuffix=blob.core.windows.net**

It should be

AccountName=account;AccountKey=XXX;**BlobEndpoint=https://account-secondary.blob.core.windows.net**

Hope this solution works for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small extension beyond @gaurav's succinct answer:

You can assume that when you do writes, followed immediately by reads, you will always get the latest data (that is, the replicas inside the region are not *eventually-consistent*; it's strong consistency).

The only option for reading from a non-primary, is when you configure for read-only geo-replicated storage. Then you may choose to read to (but not write from) storage in the alternate (secondary) region, by using `storageaccountname-secondary` instead of `storageaccountname` in the connection string.